# How is the distinction of left and right in space related to the orientation of screw?

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

In Dr. Hermann Weyl's book 'symmetry', he explains the difference between left and right as

> In space the distinction of left and right concerns the orientation of a screw. If you speak of turning left you mean that the sense in which you turn combined with the upward direction from foot to head of your body forms a left screw.

What is meant by that?

Comment: Try using a screwdriver to drive a wood screw into a soft block of wood. Which way of turning the screwdriver works better: to the left or to the right?

Comment: Um.. I just knew what is meant by left and right screw, but I still cannot understand his point. Could you help? He says 'If you speak of turning left you mean that the sense in which you turn combined with the upward direction from foot to head of your body forms a left screw'. It seems to me to be a right screw, if one is turning left(clockwise seen from foot?) and goes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try staring hard at this picture.

[image]

It should be clear that, to drive this screw into a block of wood, it has to be rotated clockwise from the top.

This is a "right screw", and the orientation of this screw is different from that of a "left screw", which has to be rotated anticlockwise.

Comment: Dr.Weyl states 'If you speak of turning left you mean that the sense in which you turn combined with the upward direction from foot to head of your body forms a left screw', and I feel confused because if, from foot to head is upward arrow, and we are turning left, then shouldn't this be the right-handed screw? I think turn left means anticlockwise, and since from foot to head is upward, I get that when I turn anticlockwise, I move up, which is a right screw. But he states it is a left-screw. I can't see what is wrong with my interpretation. Could you help?

Comment: It *is* a left screw. Consider a line moving out vertically in front of you (like if your nose became really long). What happens to this line if you rotate clockwise?